# 'wp' hook supposed to trigger when editing a post?

Tags: wp-admin, hooks, actions, post-editor

I'm trying to figure out if this is by design, a bug or a feature I should try to request. I created a plugin and added the following code:

```
function test_wp() {
    echo '<div style="position: absolute; border: 3px solid #dcdcdc; background: #ffffff; padding: 20px; left: 200px; top: 100px; font-size: 30px; z-index: 9999;">It worked</div>';
}
add_action('wp', 'test_wp');
```

I'm essentially looking for instances where the ['wp' hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp) does/doesn't get triggered. It doesn't load on the admin dashboard, which is obvious since it's not loading any single WP object. Whenever I click into "All Posts" it does appear to get triggered.  Which is what I expected to happen.

Now, when clicking edit on any existing post, it appears 'wp' hook is not getting triggered on the post editor pages. It seems to me that the 'wp' hook should be getting called here, since it's loading a post and it's respective data directly onto this page. Yet the trigger doesn't seem to load.

Am I missing some logic behind it not loading here?

I am able to trigger the ['posts_selection' hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/posts_selection), which according to the [Action Reference list](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) happens right before 'wp' hook runs.  That said, I have no idea what 'posts_selection' is actually doing, since the documentation for it is empty.

I am currently running WordPress 3.6.1 and had the same issue in 3.6.0.  I haven't tried any versions prior to 3.6.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, `'wp'` action hook **is not** triggered on post edit page.

This hook is a query-related hook, it means that it runs everytime a posts query is triggered from an url.

For this reason it's a more `frontend` hook (it runs on every frontend request), even if is triggered in *some* edit pages, more specifically, in the admin pages that do a post query: `edit.php` (so post, page and every cpt list) and `upload.php` (that show a list of media, i.e. attachment post type).

When you are on single post edit, no post query is triggered, because the current post is retrieved by WP with `get_post()`.

`'posts_selection'` is another query-related hook, so it runs on every frontend request and on admin pages that run a post query (just like the `'wp'` hook).

If you need and *early* action hook that runs on post edit page, a good idea is look at `'load-post.php'` hook (one of the [`'load-{$page}'`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/load-%28page%29) hooks), that is fired **only** on post edit page.

In a function that runs on that hook, you can access to the post id being edited using `$_GET['post']` variable.

Comment: If there any block scheme or image where we can check what and where is called? Bc this list doesn't show anything right. It say admin has wp action but edit page it is not admin? https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

Comment: load-edit.php doesnt called on single edit page and also it called on list of posts to edit